# Create a background and banner that extend beyond container to fit browser screen. Similar to Obama's website

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I want my background image and banner to extend beyond the container to allow it to fit and center to different browser screen sizes.  I have created divs for each just need to know what settings each need to have.

The look I want is very similar to Obama's website.
http://www.barackobama.com/

Comment: Look at the CSS and HTML source code. It's not that complicated.

Comment: Could you please show your code or something relevant so we can see where you are facing problem. By the way the site you gave is very simple. make header Div fixed and the images in center, take it in a div and set margin:0 auto; the image will always in center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use percent width and height. This way,

```
<img src="image" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yP4z7/